# How to format md5.ComputeHash for console window without question marks

Tags: c#

I have a simple code to generate checksum for files to compare whether a file is new or not.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead("output_log.txt"))
            {
                var checksum = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream))
                                           .Replace("-", "‌​")
                                           .ToLower();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(checksum);
                Console.Write(checksum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The outputs:

**Debug.WriteLine**:

> a4‌​88‌​ad‌​a7‌​cc‌​db‌​a7‌​31‌​25‌​a9‌​e0‌​44‌​75‌​44‌​86‌​7c

**Console.Write**:

> a4??88??ad??a7??cc??db??a7??31??25??a9??e0??44??75??44??86??7c

I think the output of the MD5 digest function is a binary sequence of bytes, not a printable character string.

How can I print md5 digest as human readable representation as the output in Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: Yuck. Nasty string replacement. `string.Concat(md5.ComputeHash(stream).Select(b => b.ToString("x2")))` is a nice one liner that isn't affected by `BitConverter`'s encoding weirdness.

Comment: Nice Linq solution better than my answer.

Comment: BitConverter.ToString() is not broken.  The "" you use in the Replace() call is not as empty as it looks.  It contains 2 Unicode codepoints, U+200C and U+200B.  Such are the joys of copy/pasting code from a web page :).  Just backspace it and type it in again.

Comment: Is there any option in VS that I could turn on to see those magic Unicode codepoints?

Answer (score 0):

I cant say for sure why but doing the replace outside of the BitConverter line fixes it.

```
var checksum = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream))                                               
                           .ToLower();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(checksum);
checksum = checksum.Replace("-", "");
Console.Write(checksum);
```

See @Hans Passant's comment on why this works. Summary "" actually replaces the character with two unicode characters.

Console output:

> d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

Edit: My hash string is different from yours obviously because we aren't using the same file figured I would add this to the answer.

Comment: Given @HansPassant's comment, you can now say for sure that you fixed it because you retyped the `""`.

Comment: Haven’t tried it yet. But I assume that’s the issue. I’ll do it when I get back to work.. thanks